# Use single script for multiple input selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins, keyboard

I want to change the code below to have only one id in multiple places instead of using multiple ids (`keyboard1`, `keyboard2`, `keyboard3`,  etc.).

I need to use the script for multiple input boxes.

```
<div class="col-md-6 mt-20 flip">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input id="search_field" type="text" id="" class="search_field form-control">
        <span class="input-group-addon key-show"><i class="fa fa-keyboard-o"></i></span>
    </div>
    <div id="keyboard" class="keyboard show-allkey"></div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6 mt-20 flip">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input id="search_field1" type="text" id="" class="search_field form-control">
        <span class="input-group-addon key-show"><i class="fa fa-keyboard-o"></i></span>
    </div>
    <div id="keyboard1" class="keyboard show-allkey"></div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 mt-20 flip">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input id="search_field2" type="text" id="" class="search_field form-control">
        <span class="input-group-addon key-show"><i class="fa fa-keyboard-o"></i></span>
    </div>
    <div id="keyboard2" class="keyboard show-allkey"></div>
</div>

$('#keyboard').jkeyboard({      
  layout: "english",
  input: $('#search_field')
});
$('#keyboard1').jkeyboard({     
  layout: "english",
  input: $('#search_field1')
});
$('#keyboard2').jkeyboard({     
  layout: "english",
  input: $('#search_field2')
});
```

My demo url: https://rawgit.com/saravanasksp/jkeyboard/master/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop over the class in an `each` loop. This will expose individual instances and allow you to traverse to get the associated search field

```
$('.keyboard').each(function() {
  const $input = $(this)
  $input.jkeyboard({
    layout: "english",
    input: $input.prev().find('.search_field')
  });    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it :

```
$('.keyboard').each(function() {
    $(this).jkeyboard({
        layout: "english",
        input: $(this).prev('.input-group').find('.search_field');
    });
});
```